# how to differentiate two more Xml tags its containing same name in iPhone using ns xml parser

Tags: iphone, xml, xcode

i'm new to iPhone development. i have two xml tags has a same name. how to differentiate this two tags. i mean how to identify when first tag will be closed

```
   <data>
    <level>0</level>
    <type>video</type>
    <file>file_CTcE96nTfP3sXIQ8.wmv</file>
    <position>0,0,640,360</position>
    <duration>121</duration>
</data>
<data>
    <level>0</level>
    <type>image</type>
    <file>file_CTNJ1da7ntcTGmxd.jpg</file>
    <position>640,0,1024,360</position>
    <duration>121</duration>
</data>
<data>
    <level>0</level>
    <type>image</type>
    <file>file_CTAo1yLWaZqXkpic.png</file>
    <position>0,360,337,480</position>
    <duration>121</duration>
</data>
```

i have implement these methods.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"data"]) {

    }
```

}

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
???
}
```

here is there three data tags there. i want to put all each data tags in three array. how can i achieve that.i mean like this

```
data1(file,type,position,duration)
data2(file,type,position,duration)
data3(file,type,p‌​osition,duration)
```

Comment: Had you try NSXMLParser previously?

Comment: @KAREEM MAHAMMED no i'm new to iPhone..

Comment: @KAREEM MAHAMMED not yet can you help me..

Comment: @moorthy what exactly you are looking for put all values in array which contain in between tags data and again put those into another array?

Comment: @KAREEM MAHAMMED here is three data tags there i want to put all each data tags in three array. how can i achieve that.i mean like this data1 (file,type,position,duration)data2(file,type,position,duration)data3(file,type,p‌​osition,duration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In didStartElement

```
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"data"]) {
    data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    level = [NSMutableString alloc] init];
    type = [NSMutableString alloc] init];
    position = [NSMutableString alloc] init];
    duration = [NSMutableString alloc] init];
}
```

Then in didEndElement

```
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"data"]) {
    [data setObject:type forKey:@"type"];
    [data setObject:position forKey:@"position"];
    [data setObject:duration forKey:@"duration"];
    [dataList addObject:data];
}
```

U need to add foundCharacters delegate method and assign values to strings here

```
if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"type"]) {
    [type appendString:string];
}

if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"position"]) {
    [position appendString:string];
}
if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"duration"]) {
    [duration appendString:string];
}
```

level, position and duration are to be parsed as normal tags..

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName 
{

     if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"data"]) 
       {

       }
}
```

Comment: i already done this when that element tag will end that time i want to store that on each array for each and every end tag.?